# C++ Get all variables by object type

Tags: c++, object

Is it possible to get all variables in memory by type?

Example:

```
string container[]; //Array that will contain the objects
GetAllObjects(string, &container); //Get all the objects by specified object type
```

Comment: In C++ the syntax would be `std::vector<std::string*> container = std::string::get_all_objects()`. You don't want a **copy** of all strings. But as deviantfan correctly notes, `std::string` does not have such a list, no does any other standard C++ type

Answer (score 1):

No, not generally.

If the objects itself maintain a list of them, ie. the constructor adds it´s own object to some global array/list and the destructor removes it, then yes. But without changes to the class, it isn´t possible.
If you plan to implement such a list thing, pay attention to multi-thread locking.